# C# Download Empty Blob from MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I'm trying to manage the files from MySQL using C# window form.
here is the code to verify the files before download the files (longblob).
I found out the problem when even the data(user 1 in resume) is empty ,the system still allow me to download an empty file to save.

Question

1. why reader["resume"] is not equals to Null / empty when it do not contains any value in it ?
2. how to check the empty data(longblob) from MySql

   ```
       MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = @email", db.getConnection());

       MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

       while (reader.Read())
       {
           if (reader["resume"] != DBNull.Value) <--- data is empty

           {
              // download file
           }
           else
           {
              // do not download
           }

       }
   ```

[image]

[image]

download file function

```
                byte[] fileData = (byte[])reader.GetValue(0);
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                        {
                            bw.Write(fileData);
                            bw.Close();

                        }
                    }
```

Comment: debug your code. What is is stored in `reader["resume"]`? Empty `byte[]`? `null`?

Comment: reader["resume"].ToString() //System.Byte[]

Comment: for user2 i uploaded a pdf into it,
for user1 it is empty

Comment: even the database in empty in MySql , i still able to download an empty pdf , why ?

Comment: If there is an **empty** blob (note, that `empty != null`) in MySQL - you will get an empty `byte[]` (like `new byte[0]`). `DBNull.Value` is an empty byte array too, but it is another object, so `new byte[0] != DBNull.Value`. If your db field is not nullable, you can safely check `if (((byte[])reader["resume"]).Length == 0)`

Comment: it is working now, thanks !